# Different boundary in multipart/form-data header and request body using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

I have an issue with sending `formData` using `XMLHttpRequest`.
In my request header, the `Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-----MochXhr1234`,
but in the `formData` boundaries, it is `------WebKitFormBoundary3sEuJp62GyQo49IC`.
I didn't use any proxy or change headers anywhere. I also didn't set the `Content-type` manually.

I'm expecting the boundaries to be equal.

Comment: Can you add your JavaScript code to the question. Just the part that does the XMLHttpRequest. And a question: Where can you see the two different boundary strings?